# Layout Android, A Three Columns App

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm a beginner in Android development, and I would like to create an application composed by three main columns, one for a list, a second one for text/description, and a last one for a MapView. The target is an Android 3.0 tablet, to begin I was trying to use Fragments but It was 'impossible' to use a MapView with the fragment system so I'm trying to do it in another way.

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=15347

However I'm a bit lost with all possible layouts that I can use... And more, I have to add the possibility to hide (for example) the MapView (third columns), so if you have any clue...

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use LinearLayout with a horizontal orientation and then hide the controls when they need to be hidden?

See: http://www.learn-android.com/2010/01/05/android-layout-tutorial/4/

Comment: But if I hide my third column (for example) will the second column resized automatically?

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use whatever layout you want, but a good start will probably be a horisontal linear layout for the columns, then have sub-layouts for each column.

You can hide (sub-)layouts by setting the visibility attribute.